# ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y`

Tags: plotly-dash

I am not able to get the heatmap in Plotly and getting ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references

```
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,value):
dff = df[df['Year'] == value]   

fig = px.density_heatmap(
                          
                          x=dff[dff['Population'] == xaxis_column_name]['Pop. Density (per sq. mi.)'],
                          y=dff[dff['Area (sq. mi.)'] == yaxis_column_name]['Pop. Density (per sq. mi.)'],
                          text_auto=True,
                          hover_name=dff[dff['Country'] == yaxis_column_name]['Region'])
return fig
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to plot a px.line chart by passing a dataframe to px.line, and I could not find an answer online that solved my specific problem. I'm not sure if your problem was caused by the same thing as mine, but I found that my error was occurring when I tried to pass an empty dataframe to px.line - the data in the dataframe that I am passing to the px.line chart changes each time the script is re-run, and sometimes there is no data in the dataframe, that's why I get an empty dataframe sometimes. To solve the problem, I simply wrote an if statement that stated: if the dataframe that I was trying to pass to px.line was empty, then I passed a "dummy" dataframe to px.line with the same column headers but with only one row of data that was all zeros, else, pass the originally intended dataframe, like this:

```
# orig_df is the dataframe I am passing to px.line
empty_df = orig_df.empty
if empty_df = True:
    orig_df = pandas.DataFrame({'Col1':[0], 'Col2':[0], 'Col3':[0]}) # column names are same as in orig_df
else:
    orig_df = orig_df
```

It solved the problem everywhere I was passing a dynamic dataframe into a px.line chart. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head.  I had a similar issue when trying to take in a live data feed to build some analytics.  I could not understand the issue as it worked many times and would stop (no code change).  I found that I was limited to a certain number of requests... So when that limit was hit and I got an empty dataframe... same error...